# Remove characters after space before a comma

Tags: regex

I have a string:

```
stuff.more AS field1, stuff.more AS field2, blah.blah AS field3
```

Is there a way I can use regex to extract anything to the right of a space, up-to and including a comma leaving:

```
field1, field2, field3
```

I cannot get the proper regex syntax to work for me.

Comment: **Try writing something yourself** and then if it doesn't work, bring it to us to help you along. You start it, we help. We don't write it for you.  Show us the actual code that you've tried and then we can help you from there.  Chances are you'll get pretty close to the answer if you just try it yourself first.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
(\w+)(?:,|$)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/bbA1wu0S246C-om4)

- `\w` is a alphanumeric character (you can replace this with `[^ ]` if you want any character except a space)
- `+` means one or more character
- `?:` makes a capture group not a capture group
- `,|$` means the end of the string is either a `,` or the end of the line

**note:** `()` denotes a capture group

please read more about [regex here](http://www.regular-expressions.info/) and use [debugexx.com](http://www.debuggex.com/) to experiment.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation.  One question to help me further understand, how would I do the exact inverse?  Select everything other than what is captured in the pattern you gave?

Comment: @JeffreyKramer `(.+?)\w+(?:,|$)` That's how you would do the inverse. You should put it into debuggex to see how it works :).

Answer (score 2):

> Is there a way I can use regex to extract anything to the right of a space up-to and including a comma...

You could do this with either a non capturing group for your `,` or use a look ahead.

```
([^\s]+)(?=,|$)
```

Regular expression:

```
(                 group and capture to \1:
 [^\s]+           any character except: whitespace (\n,
                  \r, \t, \f, and " ") (1 or more times)
)                 end of \1
(?=               look ahead to see if there is:
  ,               a comma ','
  |               OR
  $               before an optional \n, and the end of the string
)                 end of look-ahead
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 /[^ ]+(,|$)/
```

should do it. `(,|$)` allows for your last entry in the line without a comma.